# UIWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest not called in iOS 4.3

Tags: javascript, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

UIWebView's shouldStartLoadWithRequest is fired by javascript with

```
window.location = updateappdata://type/viewName/;
```

and it works perfectly in ios 5.0, 5.1, 6.0

However in ios 4.3 only some of updateappdata:// callbacks are called, not all shouldStartLoadWithRequest is called. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure they are all fired ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in setting uiwebviews scrollview's delegate to viewcontroller through subview.

```
if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
{
     [((UIScrollView *)subview) setDelegate: self];
}
```

Since in iOS 5.0+ there is .scrollView property, everything worked correctly there.